# I'm trying to get data from Parse and display it as a UILabel but I'm not getting any results

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

When I run this code it does not update the alertLabel to the message I have set on parse. Iim not getting any errors, and the label is correctly linked to my ViewController class.

I'm very new to coding so I would appreciate you help. Thanks in advance.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var alertLabel: UILabel!

    var output : PFObject!
    let theObjectID = "M0qEFWMxYI"
    let theClass = "bobcatStatus"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func displayData() {
        var thisQuery = PFQuery(className: theClass)
        thisQuery.getObjectWithId(theObjectID)

        if let alertOutput = output["alertMessage"] as? String {
        alertLabel.text = alertOutput
        }

        else {
            alertLabel.text = "Error loading data."
        }
    }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Xcode 6.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@brianprsly i am assuming you are trying to get a record from parse class using object id, try to implement below code in your project. Let me know if it helps you.

**Ref : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects**

```
var query = PFQuery(className: theClass)
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(theObjectID) {
   (theClassObj: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if error == nil && theClassObj != nil {
      println(theClassObj)
      if let alertOutput = theClassObj["alertMessage"] as? String {
         alertLabel.text = alertOutput
      }else {
         alertLabel.text = "Error loading data."
      }
   } else {
      println(error)
   }
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error at

if let alertOutput = theClassObj["alertMessage"] as? String {

It says "String?' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'"

Comment: Can you tell me what its printing for theClassObj?

Comment: It's the data it's supposed to be printing is just a String that says "No current alerts"

Thanks for you help